# Any script to strip out the compiled source in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, c-preprocessor

In my C++ file, I have

```
#ifdef DEBUG 
    then blah
#else 
    blooh.
```

I want to strip out all text that does not get compiled after preprocessing, so that if `DEBUG` is not defined, then all statement of the form:

```
#ifdef DBUG 
    /* some debug code */ 
#endif
```

gets stripped out of the source.

EDIT: Here is an example :

```
#include <iostream>
//#define DEBUG
int main(){
  #ifdef DEBUG
      cout << "In debug\n";
  #endif
     cout << "hello\n";
  return 0;
 }
```

And after running the script , the output should be

```
#include <iostream>
//#define DEBUG
int main(){
  cout << "hello\n";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: isnt that what the preprocessor does?

Comment: No. I suppose the OP doesn't want `#define`d symbols replaced, other `#ifdef` evaluated, `#include`s inserted, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is just running the preprocessor not good enough? For example `g++ -E`?

Comment: I just tried it, but it also generates the stl's code. To be more clear I just want the same CPP without the stl generated code, but just the code under #ifdef stripped out.

Answer (score 1):

Just run your compiler's preprocessor with the appropriate defines. On Windows, this would be `cl /EP file` and on Linux `gcc -E`. Most likely, you'll have to pass your defines as well, using `-DFoo`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question, but [Google](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c+partial+preprocessor) does:

- [A Partial Preprocessor for C](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/cppp.html)
- [cpp-partial](http://uazu.net/freeware/cpp-partial/) -- preprocessor directive partial evaluator

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor does this.

You can use `g++ -E somefile.cpp` to see what it generates.